# How to Include Variable inside Class in php

Tags: php

i have some file test.php

```
<?PHP
    $config_key_security = "test";
?>
```

and i have some class

test5.php

```
 include test.php
       class test1 {
                function test2 {
                   echo $config_key_security;
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
   class test1 {
            function test2 {
               global $config_key_security;
               echo $config_key_security;
         }
    }
```

or

```
   class test1 {
            function test2 {
               echo $GLOBALS['config_key_security'];
         }
    }
```

Having your class rely on a global variable isn't really best practice - you should consider passing it in to the constructor instead.

Answer (score 15):

Have your config file create an array of config items. Then include that file in your class's constructor, and save its value as a member variable. This way, all your config settings are available to the class.

test.php:

```
<?
$config["config_key_security"] = "test";
$config["other_config_key"] = true;
...
?>
```

test5.php:

```
<?
class test1 {
    private $config;

    function __construct() {
        include("test.php");
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function test2{
        echo $this->config["config_key_security"];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This should be the chosen answer

Comment: `test5.php` is best way

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to include test.php inside of the test2 method.  That will make the variable's scope local to the function.

```
   class test1 {
            function test2 {
               include('test.php');
               echo $config_key_security;
         }
    }
```

Still not a good practice though.

Comment: So long as it is not abused, this is a very useful way of allowing run-time configuration of classes.  It also allows you to separate program logic from presentation by pulling the "template" portion of a function out and placing it in an include.

Comment: Worked for me and fastest and simplest.  It's for a tiny project (<1K lines) and I only needed to do it in one place.

Answer (score 5):

Using __construct() method.

```
include test.php;
$obj = new test1($config_key_security);
$obj->test2();

class test1
{
    function __construct($config_key_security) {
        $this->config_key_security = $config_key_security;
    }

    function test2() {
        echo $this->config_key_security;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the way I prefer to do it is this:

In test.php

```
define('CONFIG_KEY_SECURITY', 'test');
```

and then:

in test5.php

```
include test.php
   class test1 {
            function test2 {
               echo CONFIG_KEY_SECURITY;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the $GLOBALS variable array and put your global variable as element in it.

*For example:*
File: configs.php

```
<?PHP
    $GLOBALS['config_key_security'] => "test";
?>
```

*File: MyClass.php*

```
<?php
require_once 'configs.php';
class MyClass {
  function test() {
    echo $GLOBALS['config_key_security'];
  }
}
```