# php include_once not work in class

Tags: php

I'm working to convert a project to multilanguage
but I have problems with require_once("../idioma/lang.br.php"); below

```
require_once("../idioma/lang.br.php");
require_once("../classe/class.usuario.dao.php");

Class UsuarioBLL 
{
    public function CadastraUsuario($campos)
    {
        $msg = array();
        // senha
        if(strlen($campos['senha']) >= 6 && strlen($campos['senha']) <= 30)
            array_push($msg,$user["TAMANHO_SENHA"]);

        if ($campos['senha'] != $campos['csenha'])
            array_push($msg, $user["SENHA_DIFERENTE"]);     

        $dao = new UsuarioDAO();
```

in

```
array_push($msg,$user["TAMANHO_SENHA"]);
```

the array variable

```
$user["TAMANHO_SENHA"]
```

is **null**

this is a include

```
<?php
//cadastro usuario
$user = array();
$user["PREENCHER_TUDO"]  = "Por favor preencha todos os campos.";
$user["TAMANHO_SENHA"]   = "Senha deve conter entre 6 a 30 digitos.";
```

if I do a  var_dump ($ user); before class

```
require_once("../idioma/lang.br.php");
require_once("../classe/class.usuario.dao.php");
var_dump ($ user);
Class UsuarioBLL 
{
    public function CadastraUsuario($campos)
    {
        $msg = array();
        // senha
        if(strlen($campos['senha']) >= 6 && strlen($campos['senha']) <= 30)
            array_push($msg,$user["TAMANHO_SENHA"]);

        if ($campos['senha'] != $campos['csenha'])
            array_push($msg, $user["SENHA_DIFERENTE"]);       

        $dao = new UsuarioDAO();
```

the system print

```
array(2) { 
["PREENCHER_TUDO"]=> string(35) "Por favor preencha todos os campos." ["TAMANHO_SENHA"]=> string(39) "Senha deve conter entre 6 a 30 digitos." 
}
```

the require_once("../classe/class.usuario.dao.php");

```
 $dao = new UsuarioDAO();
```

its working

I did a test
I create

```
class UserLang {
    public $user;
     function __construct() {
         $this->user["PREENCHER_TUDO"] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.";
    }
}
```

and it works now

```
$e = new UserLang();
echo $e->user["PREENCHER_TUDO"];
```

whyyy with class work 
and an array out of a class does not work?

I do not know what is happening

Thank you for your help

Comment: No need to `echo var_dump()`, just `var_dump()`.

Comment: You should read this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797380/how-to-include-variable-inside-class-in-php. Also as a note it is much more preferable to copy and paste code rather then screenshots. Also as that answer saws using global variables is super bad practice.

Comment: You should post your code rather than images.  Don't post the whole script though, just the excerpts that are needed for use to understand the problem.

Comment: i arrange post scripts

Comment: Please see the post again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class cannot see what is outside. If you mean for the class to work on a specific user dataset, you should make it a class property. Here's the simplest way:

```
Class UsarioBLL{
    public $user; //needs to be set before other functions can use it
}
```

After you create the object, set the user

```
$usario = new UsarioBLL();
$usario->user = $user; //now  the class can see the user data!
```

After you've done this, your `CastradaUsario` function will see the data.

> why with class work and an array out of a class does not work?

Note that your `require_once("../idioma/lang.br.php")` inserts the `$user` array above the class definition.  Your problem has to do with [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). When you define the array outside of your class, the class members cannot see it

```
$user = [...];
Class UsarioBLL{
// $user is undefined here.
}
```

To gain visibility, you need to pass the data and store it in a class variable. The simplest way is in my original answer above.  Another way is to pass data to the class constructor:

```
Class UsarioBLL{
    private $user;
    __construct($input_data){this->user = $input_data}
}
```

`__construct` is called when a new object is created. So create your new object like so:

```
$usario = new UsarioBLL($user); //will call __construct and pass $user
```

Comment: yes I can pass the array as a parameter

but because "class.usuario.dao.php" include working?

below the line of $dao = new UsuarioDAO();

It does not display error

should not this also presenting error?

Comment: Please see the post again

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up your question. I've edited my answer

Comment: Work .... Class UsuarioBLL 
{
    public function CadastraUsuario($campos)
    {
        require_once("../idioma/lang.br.php");
        $msg = array();
        // senha
        if(strlen($campos['senha']) >= 6 && strlen($campos['senha']) <= 30)
            array_push($msg,$user["TAMANHO_SENHA"]);